# Derivability of minimum function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in this way $f(x_1,x_2,x_3):=minimum\{x_1^2,x_2^2,x_3^2\}$.

I want to prove that there are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $f$ isn't derivable (where some derivatives don't exist).

Here is my reasoning, I hope someone will tell me if I'm right or not.

Consider the point $P=(1,-1,2)$. I want to prove that $f$ is not derivable in $P$, in particular that it's not defined $(\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}})_P$. I have computed the two limits

$lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(1+h,-1,2)-f(1,-1,2)}{h}=\frac{1-1}{h}=0$

$lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(1+h,-1,2)-f(1,-1,2)}{h}=lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{(1+h)^2-1}{h}=lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{h^2-2h}{h}=-2$

And since they are different we can say that $(\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}})_P$ doesn't exist. In particular $f$ isn't derivable in any point $P=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $x_i^2=x_j^2$.

Is it right?

Comment: If $z_1= z_2$, then the minimum is constant valued.

Comment: sorry, I corrected it, I hope it's clear now what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is correct.  Consider the simpler two-dimensional case : f($x_1$,$x_2$) = minimum($x_1^2$, $x_2^2$).  This is the minimum of two shapes: the 'vertical gutter' g($x_1$,$x_2$) = $x_1^2$, and the 'horizontal gutter' h($x_1$,$x_2$) = $x_2^2$.  The surface derived by taking the minimum of these two functions clearly has non-differentiable 'creases' along the diagonals.  The three variable case is similar.